# The equivalent of the strcpy function in c, int main and some interpretations

Tags: c

The equivalent of function `strpcy()` would be:

```
char *strcpy(char *d, char *s)
{
    int i = 0;
    while (s[i]) {
        d[i] = s[i];
        i++;
    }
    d[i] = '\0'; // or d[i] = 0;
    return d;
}
```

Why it came to an end `'\0'`?
And how it should look int main () for two strings of characters?

Comment: Please indent your code. This is __very__ important. And what is your question?

Comment: A string ends in `'\0'` by definition, otherwise it is a plain `char` array.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "Why it came to an end '\0'" or "how it should look int main () for two strings of characters".  Could you please be more specific about what you are asking?

Comment: I want to make a main in which to read two strings   to use the function above me and I do not understand why
after while it appears at the end d [i] = '\ 0'

Comment: @Jeryy1994 In C, a _string_ must always end with a _null character_, else it is not a string.  `d[i]='\0';` insures `d` points to a string.

Comment: @Jeryy1994 you should read the chapter dealing with strings in your c text book.

Comment: Thanks @chux    , i understand ,can you give me an example of int main to call this function?

Comment: How do i call it in int main ? :))

Comment: Question. If your source string is empty (meaning that the first character is zero) would you expect a zero to be written into the first character of the destination string?

Comment: Since you're going to want to copy the first character whether or not it is a zero, you can rewrite the `while` loop as a `do-while` loop — in other words, a loop that stops _after_ copying a zero — and then you don't need to explicitly put in the zero value on the end of the destination string.

Answer (score 2):

the posted code contains a lot of unnecessary statements.

Suggest:

```
char *myStrcpy( char *d, char *s)
{
    char *dest = d;

    while( *d++ = *s++ );

    return dest;
}
```

How to call it:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    char destination[1024];
    char source[] = "source string";

    myStrcpy( destination, source );

    puts( destination );
}
```

Comment: Minor: To closer mimic C's `strcpy()`, could use `char *s` --> `const char *s`.

Comment: @chux,  We could also modify the code to move much larger numbers of bytes at each iteration; however, that means a lot of complexity is moving the first few and last few bytes.

Comment: True, [that](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3629249/user3629249) would be a _performance_ enhancement.   The `const` idea is a _functional_ improvement as it increase applicability: allows a `const char *` as a source.